# CSS: Hover target area at 50% of the item's height

Tags: css, hover

I would like, same as when you [hover a GIF shot on Dribbble](https://dribbble.com/shots?list=animated), display a div with infos when the cursor is after/at 50% from top of the item height.

**Tested example**
I made this, this is working but a bit tricky… especially when you mouseout.
— http://codepen.io/anon/pen/meZbJK

**Used CSS code**

```
.item {
    position:relative; width:960px;

    &--infos {
        opacity:0;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        padding:0 10%;
        text-align:center;
        background:transparentize(#a7ecf8, 0.075);
        transition:opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
    }
    p {
        position:relative;
        padding:0;
        top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%);
    }
    strong {
        display:inline-block;
        margin-bottom:10px;
    }
    time {
        color:#959595;
        font-size:14px;
    }

    &--infos-target {
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        float:left;
        width:100%;
        height:50%;
    }
    &--infos-target:hover &--infos {
        opacity:1;
        top:-100%;
        height:200%;
    }
```

}

Comment: What is the problem with your codepen? It seems to work fine to me. Are you wanting the info to disappear when you hover the top half of the image again?

Comment: The overlay is larger than the image, is that by design? Can you exactify the phrase "a bit tricky"?

Comment: @CaldwellYSR when you mouseout the area it's losing the height, because of the hover code I used. I would like to avoid this effect…

Comment: @MrLister that's just for the example, don't worry about the design.

Comment: I see... does your info div need to be a child of the target div? Essentially the issue is that your target div is the parent and has 50% height that is being changed when you hover. If you made the target div and the info div separate, you could define the height of the info div on it's own.

Comment: @flks did the z-index trick work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I made edits to your codepen to make it work.

Essentially, I took `--infos` out of `--infos-target` and used the `~` selector to grab it on hover. With that, I didn't have to do the `top: -100%; height: 200%` hack anymore.

<s>Combine that with `pointer-events: none` on `--infos` and you're good to go.</s>

Using `z-index` you can position the target above the info section and you're good to go.

The biggest issue here is that you cannot have links inside the info section because of `pointer-events: none`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmLrgp

**HTML**

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/960/250/1" alt="">
    <div class="item--infos-target">
    </div>
    <div class="item--infos">
        <p>
            <strong>Item title</strong>
            <br>
            <time datetime="2015-11-05 15:23:26" class="date">Added two weeks ago</time>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.item {
    position:relative; width: 960px;
    &--infos {
        opacity:0;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        padding:0 10%;
        text-align:center;
        pointer-events: none;
             background:transparentize(#a7ecf8, 0.075);
        transition:opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
        z-index: 9;
    }
    p {
        position:relative;
        padding:0;
        top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%);
    }
    strong {
        display:inline-block;
        margin-bottom:10px;
    }
    time {
        color:#959595;
        font-size:14px;
    }

    &--infos-target {
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        float:left;
        width:100%;
        height:50%;
        z-index: 10;
    }
    &--infos-target:hover ~ &--infos {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your example! Working like a charm. Unfortunately, `pointer-events` is not supported by IE9-10 which is a need for my website :/

Comment: @flks In that case, you can use z-index to position the target above the info section. You will still have the same problem using anchors though.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need a bit of trickery here.

Firstly we need to "hide" the top 50% of the div/image from acting as a hover point/trigger.

We can use an absolutely positioned pseudo-element for that.

This means we can use the image (rather than the div) as our hover trigger...*but* this causes issues as the overlay would stop the hover effect. We can disable that with `pointer-events:none`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

.parent {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 25px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.parent img {
  display: block;
}

.info {
  position: absolute;
  top:100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,.5);
  color:white;
  line-height: 72px;
  transition:top .25s ease;
  pointer-events:none;
  z-index:3;
}

.parent::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5); /* for demo visual reference */
  z-index:2;
}

.parent img:hover ~ .info {
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/200/200" alt="" />
  <div class="info"><h3>Some Text</h3></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Me too! Can't remember what that was now. Suspect that's now at the top of the answer.